# working with a stringstream, how do i unparse these strings?

Tags: c++, parsing, tcp

i have a tcp client which gets data from a server as a stringstream. The server packs vectors (floats) in one big string and seperate these with flags. Now in my client i seperate these flags again, and store them in a string array. so each "Token" should be one vector.
But i just cant parse it back. The Strings i get look very weird, take a look:[image]

So again, all i need to do is parse this back to 3 floats. On the server side its sent like this :

```
data.addFlag(11);
data << pelvis.x() << pelvis.y() << pelvis.z();
data.addFlag(12);
data << rhip.x() << rhip.y() << rhip.z();
```

where the operator is overloaded as

```
operator<<(const float& f)
{
m_buf.append(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&f), sizeof(f));
return *this;
}
```

**EDIT:**

one token looks like this: if i try to parse it via

```
float first = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(value)
```

i get an exception.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the strings look fine, you just have to understand that when you reinterpret floats as char arrays you won't get a human readable thing. You can look here to see how floats are represented as binary: [Floating points tutorial](http://kipirvine.com/asm/workbook/floating_tut.htm)

So if you have the float 1.01 you will get binary 00111111100000010100011110101110 which is hex 0x3f8147ae if you look every byte up in a ascii table you will see that those bytes might seem garbage.

So to your problem: if you look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) you will see that each float is 4 bytes.

So assuming you have a string with 12 bytes (which you should), you should realize that there are 3 floats in there. To get them out, fetch 4 bytes at a time and reinterpret them

(untested code)

```
string data = (however you got the data)
float first = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(&data[0]);
float second = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(&data[4]);
float third = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(&data[8]);
```

That's it.

Edit: it seems i had forgotten do dereference the pointer.

See here for a working example:

http://ideone.com/FLce6y

Comment: Thank you for your help, i edited the question for more details. When i try to do it like you said, i get an exception. " Unhandled Exception at 0x013007BB "...any ideas?

Comment: What datatype is `tokens`? Try: `std::string test = tokens;` if tokens is already a string. or `std::string test = tokens.str()` if tokens is a stringstream.

Comment: ah sorry. tokens is a std::vector<std::string> tokens; which is filled by substrings of the stringstream

Comment: with a static_cast it compiles. But i should get something like this : -1.56716, what i actually get: -103..-99..20..-19.. and so on so static_cast is not what i need..

Comment: You definitively need a `reinterpret_cast`. What is the data type of `mbuf`?

Comment: m_buf is a string. dataBuf is a stringstream

Comment: on the server, the stringstream is created by stringstream << v10.get(); where .get() returs the string m_buf..then the server sends it server->send(stringstream);

Comment: Thank you Sir! That was it. i forgot the & !!finally.